# c# line chart remove extra interval

Tags: c#, charts

When I create a c# line chart with dates in the x-axis, and set the interval to 1, I get a line chart with an interval for each data point, which is exactly what I want.  However, there is an extra interval before the first data point, and after the last data point.

*Here is where I would post an image of my graph, but I can't because I don't have 10 reputation*

If I attempt to set the AxisX minimum and maximum values using ToOADate() as was suggested in several other posts, my chart area turns black.

*Here is where I'd post an image of the black graph, but I can't post it because I don't have 10 reputation*

And here is the code I'm using to create my series.

```
    Series lakeVals = new Series("LakeData");
    lakeVals.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    int i = 0;
    DateTime dateVal;
    dateVal = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        if (row[_rd.ChartType].ToString() != "")
        {
            dateVal = (DateTime)row["recdate_vc"];
            lakeVals.Points.AddXY(dateVal.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), row[_rd.ChartType]);
            lakeVals.Points[i].AxisLabel = dateVal.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = dateVal.ToOADate();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    lakeVals.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
    lakeVals.MarkerSize = 5;
    LakeChart.Series.Add(lakeVals);
    LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
    //LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = dateVal.ToOADate();
    LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
    LakeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10;
```

The commented out lines are what cause the graph to just be black.  It's probably worth mentioning that I want to keep the date values added as strings, rather than adding them as date values because if I add them as date values the graph control will attempt to space them based on how far apart the actual dates are, when all I want is to have them evenly spaced.  This is a request from my client, so please no arguing with me about how I SHOULD represent the data, it's not my choice.

Comment: You can add a link to an external image hoster. Imgur is what SO images are hosted on. - But the (very common) error is visible anyway: You wrote _ I create a c# line chart with dates in the x-axis_ but this: `lakeVals.Points.AddXY(dateVal.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),` adds strings, not dates. So you can't access the dates, which are lost but for the labels. Add the x-avalues as DateTimes!! - If you don't want a correct spacing you can set the x-axis of your series to be indexed: `Series.IsXValueIndexed`

Comment: If I add the values as dates, then set the IsXValueIndexed to true, my data line disappears.  Adding the values as strings works EXACTLY the way I want, except there is an extra interval on the left and right of my graph.

Comment: You think it is what you want because you don't understand what you do. 'If your line disappears it is because you are setting the minimum/maximum to wrong values. You can alsi play with `IntervalOffset` btw and with `IsStartedFromZero`. But do yourself a favor and have a look at the x-values! See how useless they are?